# SVG intersection of elements with transforms

Tags: svg, intersection

The [Intersection library from Kevin Lindsey](http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/) allows to easily compute intersections between several types of `svg` elements (paths, rectangles, lines...).

However, it does not seem to take into account the transformations applied via `transform="translate(x,y) rotate(r)"` to any of the objects.

```
<svg>
    <polygon id="machine" transform="translate(40,25) rotate(45)"... />
    <path id="outer" ... />
</svg>

<script>
var machine = document.getElementById("machine")
var outer = document.getElementById("outer")

var m = new Polygon(machine)
var o = new Path(outer)

Intersection.intersectPathShape(o, m) // incorrect
</script>
```

Is there a way to take the transformations applied to any element into account while computing intersections?

Comment: Is it possible to get a basic jsfiddle up with a testing example ? I think it will be quite difficult, but it may give some idea.

Comment: @Ian workin'on it

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the values of to their 'screen' values, extracting the transforms. Below are some examples for polygons and paths(except arcs):
Note on paths: Chrome deprecated pathSegList recently and now requires a polyfill,
https://github.com/progers/pathseg

```js
//---except arc paths---
function screenPath(path)
{
 var sCTM = path.getCTM()
 var svgRoot = path.ownerSVGElement

 var segList=path.pathSegList
 var segs=segList.numberOfItems
 //---change segObj values
 for(var k=0;k<segs;k++)
 {
  var segObj=segList.getItem(k)

  if(segObj.x && segObj.y )
  {
   var mySVGPoint = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
   mySVGPoint.x = segObj.x
   mySVGPoint.y = segObj.y
   mySVGPointTrans = mySVGPoint.matrixTransform(sCTM)
   segObj.x=mySVGPointTrans.x
   segObj.y=mySVGPointTrans.y
  }

  if(segObj.x1 && segObj.y1)
  {
   var mySVGPoint1 = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
   mySVGPoint1.x = segObj.x1
   mySVGPoint1.y = segObj.y1
   mySVGPointTrans1 = mySVGPoint1.matrixTransform(sCTM)
   segObj.x1=mySVGPointTrans1.x
   segObj.y1=mySVGPointTrans1.y
  }
  if(segObj.x2 && segObj.y2)
  {
   var mySVGPoint2 = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
   mySVGPoint2.x = segObj.x2
   mySVGPoint2.y = segObj.y2
   mySVGPointTrans2 = mySVGPoint2.matrixTransform(sCTM)
   segObj.x2=mySVGPointTrans2.x
   segObj.y2=mySVGPointTrans2.y
  }
 }
 //---force removal of transform--
 path.setAttribute("transform","")
 path.removeAttribute("transform")
}

//---changes all transformed points to screen points---
function screenPolygon(myPoly)
{
 var sCTM = myPoly.getCTM()
 var svgRoot = myPoly.ownerSVGElement

 var pointsList = myPoly.points;
 var n = pointsList.numberOfItems;
 for(var m=0;m<n;m++)
 {
  var mySVGPoint = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
  mySVGPoint.x = pointsList.getItem(m).x
  mySVGPoint.y = pointsList.getItem(m).y
  mySVGPointTrans = mySVGPoint.matrixTransform(sCTM)
  pointsList.getItem(m).x=mySVGPointTrans.x
  pointsList.getItem(m).y=mySVGPointTrans.y
 }
 //---force removal of transform--
 myPoly.setAttribute("transform","")
 myPoly.removeAttribute("transform")
}
```